# How to use different command-shells within one script

Tags: bash, powershell, shell, powershell-3.0

I need to automatize a task on a Windows-based machine which looks like this:

Shell1: `command`  <- this command opens shell2 in another context

Shell2: `command`  <- this command opens shell3 in another context

Shell3: `command`  <- this command operates on shell3 like any generic command

Is there a way to achieve this workflow via bash/ps1 script?

Best
Daniel

Comment: You could start a terminal running the respective shell. I do it all the time, using Zsh as shell and mintty as terminal program, both from the Cygwin toolchain, but this would work for bash too. You didn't provide much information about your software infrastructure (what kind of shell implementations are you using), but the idea is the same: Start it via some terminal application.

Comment: the infrastructure is a windows server used as domain controller, so I would rather not install cygwin and other things if not absolutely neccesary.

Comment: Then, what bash implementation do you have instead?

Comment: PS1 is a variable that controls how the prompt looks like. How is it related here? What does it mean to "open a shell2 in a context"? What is a context? What does it mean to "open a shell"? What is shell context? If this is a workflow, what work has to be done here? What does it mean to "operate on shell like a command"?

Comment: I set a misleading tag, I am sorry. I mean that I enter a command which then opens another terminal window in that program's context.